# How can I publish a single org file to multiple pdfs

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-publish

I have an org document that has confidential and non-confidential information.  I need to publish the org file to two different pdfs: one that contains all of the information from the org file and the other with the non-confidential information.

I have tried the following elisp.

```
(setq org-publish-project-alist
    '(("counselor"   :base-directory "~/Dropbox/org/"   
    :base-extension "org"    
    :publishing-directory "~/Dropbox/org/"   
    :exclude-tags "confidential"
    :recursive t
    :title "Appointments"
    :publishing-function org-latex-publish-to-pdf
    :headline-levels 4
    :exclude ".*"   
    :include ["appointments.org"]))
```

This produces an appointments.pdf document, but the confidential tags are still included.  I also don't know how to change the file name to be appointments-confidential.pdf and appointments-non-confidential.pdf.

Comment: I want this feature also [An idea for org-export requirement](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/38896/an-idea-for-org-export-requirement)

Answer (score 2):

The solution I found was to write my own publishing function.  The function is a wrapper around the `org-latex-publish-to-pdf` that also calls `rename-file`.

```
(defun publish-function-counselor-appointments (PLIST FILENAME PUB-DIR)
  (org-latex-publish-to-pdf PLIST FILENAME PUB-DIR)
  (rename-file "~/appointments.pdf" "~/counselor_appointments.pdf"))
```

My `org-publish-project-alist` looks something like this:

```
'(("counselor appointments"
   :base-directory "~/"
   :base-extension "org"
   :publishing-directory "~/"
   :exclude-tags ("confidential" "noexport")
   :publishing-function publish-function-counselor-appointments
   :headline-levels 4
   :exclude ".*"
   :include ["appointments.org"]))
```

I can create another entry in the alist that will produce a different pdf file by supplying a different publishing function.  Thus, one org file can be used to produce varying pdf files.